# 0 length slices and arrays in golang

Tags: arrays, pointers, go, slice

Was trying to figure out how 0 length arrays and slices behaved in Golang. Came up with two snippets of code (I found the code somewhere and modified it a bit to work with this)

https://play.golang.org/p/ew2YYgvpGC

https://play.golang.org/p/jm2p6L6WCG

I learnt from the website that nil arrays ([]int(nil)) have a pointer value of nil, so I decided to test it. Sure enough, that is the case. I'm just confused on make and slicing an array. It has unexpected behaviour for me.

I am really confused by the behaviour of these two. The first one runs fine on my computer and on the playground. I've noticed that the address of the first and last array is always the exact same? Why?

Why is this?

The second one is weirder. This is the exact same code as the previous one, except there are snippets of other code for the len/cap in between. It does not run on the go playground, there is an error at the last one with the sliced array, for some reason, the slice gets a length of 3 (on my computer it is 0 for the last one, and the cap for all of them is 272851504). It does run on my computer however. I noticed that the address of the first array created with make is always smaller than the last one. Its always different, and a bit smaller (the first one), why? There is no change in the code for the address of the array

Also, why does make() even create an array? How does an array of length 0 even look in memory?

Comment: You seem to be trying to figure out the language via trial and error. You would be well served by carefully reading the [Go Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec) and the [Memory Model](http://golang.org/ref/mem)

Comment: This is the hackers way to learn. I'd encourage it.

Comment: @thwd: nothing wrong with experimenting, just wanted to cover all bases first.

Comment: IMO too many down votes here.  this is a pedagogical and well intentioned post.

Answer (score 3):

> I've noticed that the address of the first and last array is always
>   the exact same? Why?
>
> Why is this?

You are basing the addresses in your function on the slice header in the function arguments. And by chance that function happens to run at the same memory address each time. Also, as an implementation detail, when you slice the original down to zero length and capacity, it doesn't zero out the Data pointer. In both your functions, the slice header is copied, so you're not even examining the original header slice to begin with.

The second example, you're not correctly reading out the slice header.
If you want to play around, you don't need to try and do pointer arithmetic, and you you can take the address of the slice directly

```
hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&slice))
```

Though, if you really want to inspect a slice header via pointer arithmetic, maybe this can better clarify what you need to do: https://play.golang.org/p/GL6NtyPNs8

```
func InspectSlice(slice *[]int) {
    // Get the header directly by converting it to a reflect.SliceHeader
    hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(slice))

    // Create a header for comparison via pointer manipulation
    address := (uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(slice))
    lenAddr := address + unsafe.Sizeof(address)
    capAddr := lenAddr + unsafe.Sizeof(int(0))

    unsafeHdr := reflect.SliceHeader{
        Data: *(*uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(address)),
        Len:  *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(lenAddr)),
        Cap:  *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(capAddr)),
    }

    fmt.Printf("Real Header:  %#v\n", *hdr)
    fmt.Printf("UnsafeHeader: %#v\n", unsafeHdr)

}
```

> Also, why does make() even create an array?

Make doesn't create an array, and what you have labeled as `array` is just a slice literal.

> How does an array of length 0 even look in memory?

It doesn't look like anything. It consumes 0 bytes.

What you are seeing when making a zero-length slice is most likely a pointer to a global zero value array. Make a bunch zero length slices of different types, and the Data pointers will all be the same. Just as all empty `struct{}` and empty nil `interface{}` are given the same value as an optimization. This is entirely an implementation detail, as you are not expected to access that Data value. When slicing a slice back to zero length and capacity, the runtime also doesn't zero out the Data pointer. Because of these two behaviors, the Data pointer in any slice is rarely going to be nil.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/Agq_hKws6M As you can see in this code, that addPtr is pointing to the array, and not the slice header.

Comment: @aubble: stop bouncing between the Go mailing list and here. Keep the conversation on one forum or the other, otherwise you're wasting people time.

Comment: @aubble: that doesn't change my answer. I never mentioned here that addPtr isn't pointing to the array.

Comment: "You are printing out the address if the slice header in the function arguments" But i'm not. I am printing out the address of the array.

Comment: @aubble: clarified the wording here. You're passing the slice header by value, making a copy of it. Also, as an implementation detail, when you slice the original down to zero length and capacity, it doesn't zero out the Data pointer.

Comment: You don't understand what I am saying. This shouldn't matter what so ever, the pointer gets copied by value, and points to the same array. Look at this code; https://play.golang.org/p/R8ARPdZiDx. There is definitely a array from make, whereas the nil slice gives me a error. The guy in the golang group explained how the compiler is making optimizations in the first code I was talking about. , I will post that discussion here for anyone who is looking for this in the future. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/77XWCS2A_cY

Comment: @aubble: I'm tiring of this game of semantics. The original response was about making an array with make, it makes a slice (since you mislabeled the slice literal, it stood to reason that you may have been confused about the two). It's perfectly reasonable that make might allocate a backing array, it's an implementation detail, but without checking the assembly or runtime source, there's no way to know if that's a valid address, or just an old value. (I'm assuming it's cruft, since an immediate append allocates again). A true, 0-length array takes no memory, just like a `struct{}`.

Comment: Yea, I guess I could have been much more clear. Completely my fault, sorry. Thanks anyways.